# Woocommerce ordering export

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to woocommerce and im not extremely experienced with php, but im trying to get a simple export order into xml for a friend of mine.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed','complete_orders',14,0);
function completed_orders($order_id)
{
$id =$post->ID;

$args = array(
            'id'            =>$id,
            'post_type'     =>'shop_order',
            'meta_key'      =>'_order_id',
            'posts_per_page'=>'-1'
             );

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);

if($my_query->have_posts()){
    $my_query->next_post();
    $customer_order = $my_query->posts;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $order->populate($customer_order);
    $orderdata = (array) $order;
    $fields = array_values($orderdata);

    $xmlOrder = new DOMDocument();
    array_to_xml($fields,$xmlOrder);
    $xmlOrder->saveXML('/wp-order/'. $order_id);

    }
```

What im getting from the above code is it will take the order id when a order is completed then turn it into an array, then i've got another method which will then turn that array into xml

```
function array_to_xml($order,$xmlOrder)
{
foreach($order as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        $n = $xmlOrder->createElement($key)
        $node->appendChild($n);
        $array2xml($n,$value);
    }
    else
    {
        $attr = $xmlOrder->createAttribute($key);
        $attr->value =$value;
        $node->appendChild($attr);
    }
}
}
```

I must be doing something wrong, if someone could help me or point me in the right direction that would be great.

EDIT:
Im not getting any response, but tbh i dont know if im doing it right. This is first time i've ever used woocommerce and there docs doesnt really say much.

Comment: Could you please specify what the expected output is and what you are currently getting (an example at least)?

Comment: Im not getting anything, or im trying to get the output incorrectly